# Okta Spring Boot Invalid Credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, okta

We are implementing authorization for our Spring Boot Web Application through the Company's Okta Server. The idea is to allow users to sign in to the company's Okta dashboard and then click on our application from there. However, we are not able to redirect users to our application API call. We have the following configuration on the Okta Application:

**Sign In Redirect URI**: https://backend-web-api.com/authorization-code/callback

**Login Initiated By**: Either Okta or APP

**Login Flow**: Redirect to app to initiate login(OIDC compliant)

**Initiate Login URI**: https://backend-web-api.com/user/authorize

We have the controller with the /user/authorize but the request is not getting redirected to this controller which we mentioned in the Initiate Login URI Requests

We are using the Okta spring Boot starter (2.1.7), Spring boot starter parent version 2.7.3 and following Security Config code

```
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http
               .csrf().disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/user/authorize*").authenticated()
               .and()
               .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
               .and()
               .oauth2Client()
               .and()
               .oauth2Login();

        http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2-> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }
```

Properties file for the same as below:

```
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://company-url.org/oauth2/default
okta.oauth2.client-id=####
okta.oauth2.client-secret=########
okta.oauth2.redirect-uri=/authorization-code/callback
```

The error we are getting is Invalid Credentials and here is the attached screenshot for the same[image]

Following is the network tab when we click on our application link through Okta dashboard.[image]

Are we missing something? Or we are not following the correct steps for the same. Please help us as we are not able to figure out through other questions and online research.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to get it resolved. The issue was multiple servers running and the authorization request from the okta through the ELB was getting propagated to different instances which in the end was causing the Invalid Credentials. We enabled ELB with the StickySessions and then the issue got resolved.